# Installation of Indefero under ubuntu

Tags: php, svn, ubuntu, indefero

I ask for your help as I try to install indefero on a virtual machine.
I followed the instructions on the official website but I'm a bit overwhelmed .

I followed the official tutorial but this is beyond me because I have a hard time realizing it.

I created in / home / www / project where I installed indefero and pluf in respective directories.

I do not know if I should also configure svn , git ... in parallel

I copied the files " idf.php " and " path.php " and I changed one of them.

i launched this command

`php migrate.php - conf = //indefero/src/IDF/conf/idf.php -a -i -d -u`

My result is

`PHP Fatal error: Pluf loadRelations :: (): Failed opening required ' IDF / relations.php ' ( include_path = ' :/ usr / share / php :/ usr / share / pear :/ home / www / project / pluf / . src ' ) in / home / www / project / pluf / src / Pluf.php on line 96`

I try with the original version of the command
`php migrate.php - conf = IDF / conf / idf.php -a -i -d -u`

The result is

`Error: Missing what to do or config file .
Usage examples :
 Upgrade all: migrate.php - conf = path / to / config.php -a
 Upgrade MyApp : migrate.php - conf = path / to / config.php - app = MyApp
 Backup MyApp : migrate.php - conf = path / to / config.php - app = MyApp -b / path / to / backup / folder [ backupname ]
 Restore MyApp : migrate.php - conf = path / to / config.php - app = MyApp -r / path / to / backup / folder backupname
 MyApp to ver. 3 migrate.php - conf = path / to / config.php - app = MyApp -v3`

Do you have any idea what I can do?

I confess I do not understand because I program more and I did not admin years
thanks